# LINUX Routing VPN traffic for specific port to host on local network

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, iptables, nat

I am connecting my Linux L1 to VPN to get a public static IP 117.xxx.xxx.xxx . This L1 machine has only one ethernet interface eth0 with ip 192.168.1.130 and VPN is connected creating interface ppp0. I want to do remote desktop with port 3389 on a host(IP 192.168.1.100) connected to linux box via router. I know it will work with NAT but I am not getting hold on proper commands.

VPN IP is pinging from the internet.Attaching the connection diagram for reference. Please help me with your inputs.

```
ETH 0
inet 192.168.1.130  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
Gateway 192.168.1.1

VPN
inet 172.xxx.xxx.xxx  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.253.242.4
```

[image: Network]

Comment: Please clarify some more with an [edit] on your question. The "*I want to*" language needs clarified some I think.... You want to RDP via 3389 on what machine and on what subnet and then you are RDP'ing to what machine and what subnet exactly? Make it clear you are coming from this subnet and going to this subnet via the TCP port 3389 or whatever. Is your VPN connection directing all local subnet to it's gateway or something and you want to give non-VPN local subnet a static route with higher precedent to point to it's gateway perhaps.

Comment: please let me know if more info is needed

Comment: You say "*I want to do remote desktop with port 3389 on a host(IP 192.168.1.100) connected to linux box via router.*"... okay so from `192.168.1.x` subnet you have a host with `192.168.1.100` that is going to RDP to what? You need it to RDP to the `192.168.1.130` host when it is connected to the VPN or something or what exactly? I'm trying to paint the picture how all this is related with the VPN and the RDP access and such and the specifics in literal terms while this host is x then I need to RDP from x over to x while it's x or whatever.... you see what I'm saying?

Comment: Maybe a diagram would help if you have something but I think it needs clarified for your traffic starting point and those specifics and what you need to go where or skate across the VPN, etc. Not too clear right now even with the interface details. I understand the int configs, help me understand from where and to where you need traffic routed

Comment: I have attached the diagram. Traffic starts from VPN IP, I will use VPN IP 117.xxx.xxx.xxx from internet to RDP on host with ip 192.168.1.100. so when I do rdp with IP 117.x.x.x it should forward that connection to  host 192.168.1.100

Answer (score 0):

Start with simple DNAT (port forwarding):

```
-A PREROUTING -d 117.xxx.xxx.xxx -m tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100
-A PREROUTING -d 117.xxx.xxx.xxx -m udp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100
```

<sup>*(Modern RDP uses both TCP and UDP transports.)*</sup>

However, the RDP server **must also use the Linux router as its default gateway.** As long as the server simply uses your main LAN router, its responses to clients will be NATed to the wrong source IP address. (That is, even though clients send connection requests to 117.xxx.xxx.xxx, they'll get a response from your main WAN IP address and be very confused.)

Finally, when the Linux router *does* receive those responses and translates them correctly, it still needs to know that they should be sent over the VPN. If your VPN client is already configured to override the default route, nothing else needs to be done. (Otherwise you would need to add "policy routing" rules.)

Comment: Is it missing something getting error iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: Iptable looks like below,Note changed host ip to 192.168.1.25

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.x.x.x      udp dpt:3389 to:192.168.1.25
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.x.x.x      tcp dpt:3389 to:192.168.1.25